# How to test an array length of a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

Still getting tripped up on what and how to spy on stuff in React Components
I've got this function, which basically filters a list and returns the matches when I type in a value for `team`:

```
findMatchesForTeam = (team, venue) => {
  if (team) {
    console.log(team) // THIS GETS THE RIGHT TEAM (e.g. Chelsea) WHEN TESTING
    return this.props.matches.filter(t => t.homeTeam === team.name || t.awayTeam === team.name)
      .map((match) => (
        this.result(match)
      ))
  }
}
```

And my test:

```
describe('other functions', () => {
  it('expects the matches array to have been filtered', () => {
    wrapper.instance().findMatchesForTeam('Chelsea');
    expect(matchesStub.length).to.equal(2);
  });
});
```

So I'm calling the method in my component and search for "Chelsea" and in the variable `matchesStub` I've got:

```
const matchesStub = [
  {awayGoals: 1, awayTeam: "Man City", homeGoals: 1, homeTeam: "Arsenal", month: "February"},
  {awayGoals: 2, awayTeam: "Man City", homeGoals: 3, homeTeam: "Chelsea", month: "February"},
  {awayGoals: 0, awayTeam: "Chelsea", homeGoals: 0, homeTeam: "Man Utd", month: "February"}
];
```

However my test says it should be length 3 (which is the initial length) and doesn't bother filtering. The code works, but the test doesn't.

Comment: What does `this.result(match)` do? Also you should keep in mind that filter creates new array. Assertions about original array do not make sense.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko result just returns a div of 4 spans with the detail of the match in i.e. goals and team names

Comment: Your function returns the filtered array, but you're not checking the return result.

Comment: @Will ok sure, but how do you mock and test that in a react component?

Comment: `expect(wrapper.instance().findMatchesForTeam('Chelsea').length).to.equal(2);` I'd suspect would work.

Comment: @Will that got 0. and then I logged it and indeed it was an empty array...

Comment: @Will figured it out, thanks!

Comment: You should add an answer below detailing your solution! It may seem weird, but that's how we do it.

Comment: @Will cool, will do that now

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Will above, this solution worked:

```
expect(wrapper.instance().findMatchesForTeam('Chelsea').length).to.equal(2)
```

well, actually that is not entirely true. the final solution was:

```
const teamToFilterBy = {name: 'Chelsea'};
expect(wrapper.instance().findMatchesForTeam(teamToFilterBy).length).to.equal(2);
```

This was because my filter method above takes an object due to it requiring the name property. In my test I was only passing it a string and so even though it was logging it correctly, clearly a string can't have a `.name` attribute on it.

thanks to all who helped me get there!